# local Printer installation on Azure VM

Tags: azure

I have one Stand alone windows VM in Azure means no Site to site or Express Route or P2S exists. So my question is how can I install the printer in the VM and print anything from that to my local printer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in Remote Desktop printer mapping - no drivers necessary since it will tunnel the print job through the RDP session back to your computer.

By the way, any infrastructure-related questions should be asked here instead -
https://superuser.com

[image: Remote Desktop Local Resources]

Comment: I forget to write exact what I am trying to achieve. I have client who is having the printer on-premise and for that client I created VM and now he is telling me to install printer on Azure VM from sitting here. I can reach the VM using RDP but how can I reach printer without any connectivity with the on-premise so am bit confused here as I am new to this printer setup. So question is how I can setup printer from here so that my client prints anything it will directly go to that printer

Comment: The answer which you have is valid only when that printer is in my network and I have installed locally in my computer and then when I do RDP with the printers check mark it will work

Comment: This is not the place for that question, post to https://superuser.com, StackOverflow is a programming site.